# Mouse Behavior on a WebPage – I don't want text being marked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mouseevent, jquery-events

I am working on a web-Based Kalendar Application (multi-user). The Application is nearly ready, but one thing is not so good. I want to give the User the chance, to mark several times at one time. That's why, i made a mousedown-function, on every field, and a mouseup-function as well. That way, I get the first marked field, and the last. All fields in the middle can be calculated by the id!

Now the problem: While I am moving the mouse, the browser marks the text. I want another mouse behavior. I want the mouse to draw a rectangle, so that the user sees, where he started, an so that no text within the document gets marked! This is very important. Do you know, how to solve the problem? I already deactivated the right-Click Menu, an set my own menu, but this is to hard for me :(. I have already searched the web with google, but actually I do not really know, which keywords could help here.

PS: I am using jQuery, maybe it could help in this situation.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a script to disable text selection:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/noselect.htm

If you have jQuery, you can use bind like:

```
$('#demo').bind('selectstart',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Nk9ec/2/

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem to work. I looked your example http://jsfiddle.net/Nk9ec/2/, but there I can select the text as well.

Comment: It works for me. You probably have your browser set to disregard selectstart. I believe you can do that in Firefox under the Advanced Javascript box.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i found out, what was wrong. Your Code is for IE only. I am using Firefox, and I optimize my Application to Firefox! Well now, i managed disabling selecting text, with that function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document)[0].oncontextmenu = function() {return false;} 
    $('#id').mousedown(function(event) {
        checkClk(event);
        return false; 
    });
});
```

The function checkClk(event) controls the Clicking-Behavior.
Beside I managed to make the mouse-Pointer standart-Pointer with css:

```
body {
    cursor: default;
}
```

All I need is now, to figure out, how I can draw a rectangle, when I move the mous, holding the left Button clicked. I want the Application look like the operating-System.
If you click and hold the mouse down, there is an Rectangle (like this: http://img21.imageshack.us/i/markiert.png/). Does anyone know, wheather this is possible without making a div, which size depends on the Mouseposition?